# Which transport protocol does IdHTTP use

Tags: delphi, indy

I have been asked by a company to document that our client only communicates to our server over the TCP protocol on a software level. I have always assumed that `IdHTTP` utilizes TCP but I am not sure how to *prove* it. I have not been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: The TIdHTTP class is a descendant of *TIdTCPConnection*, as indicated in [the Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Securing_Indy_Network_Connections). As Indy is open source, this can also be shown in the code.

Comment: you could also install wireshark and perform a trace and make a screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` is ultimately derived from `TIdTCPConnection`, so it uses **TCP** by default <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1. Though this can be changed by assigning a non-TCP based `TIdIOHandler`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property.</sup>